# Oledb - IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: c#, sql, oledbconnection

When i run the following query with OleDbConnection :-

```
"SELECT * FROM [UserLogs] order by [LogDate] OFFSET 0 ROWS"
```

I get following error :-

> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

If I skip the `OFFSET` part the query runs as it should be.

How to solve this?

Comment: show us your connection string

Comment: connection string is like this :- `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="+ path`..But the problem doesn't seem to be in connection string as removing `OFFSET` from query runs the code without error.

Comment: @Anup:- Try to set Set CommandTimeOut to 0.

Comment: Setting CommandTimeOut to 0 gives the same error.!

Comment: Oledb jet provider doesn't support OFFSET keyword. Please see this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266

Comment: @Harsh what is alternative option for using `OFFSET` in `Oledb` Jet Provider?

Comment: There isn't any direct alternative. You may have to code custom logic on front-end if you are doing this for paging.